# Function changing and returning object's value even if it is 'passed by value'

Tags: php

I am in a situation where i am mapping an array into object and then assigning it to another array. Simply making an array of object out of nested array.

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'edu_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'edu_degree' => string 'MCA' (length=3)
      'edu_institute' => string 'ECB' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'edu_id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'edu_degree' => string 'BCA' (length=3)
      'edu_institute' => string 'CET' (length=3)
```

This is the array and i am trying to convert it into this -

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(MatEducation)[11]
      private 'id' => int 1
      private 'eduId' => string '3' (length=1)
      private 'degree' => string 'MCA' (length=3)
      private 'institute' => string 'ECB' (length=3)
  1 => 
    object(MatEducation)[11]
      private 'id' => int 1
      private 'eduId' => string '4' (length=1)
      private 'degree' => string 'BCA' (length=3)
      private 'institute' => string 'CET' (length=3)
```

Here is the mapper function.

```
/**
     * @param MatEducation $obj - i am passing this object so that
     * function dont need to create 'new' object every time.if i create
     * a new object then i get the desired result.
     * @param array $arr this array contain the value to be converted.
     * @return MatEducation
     */
    public function toMatEducation(MatEducation $obj, array $arr)
    {
        $obj->setEduId($arr['edu_id']);
        $obj->setDegree($arr['edu_degree']);
        $obj->setInstitute($arr['edu_institute']);
        return $obj;
    }
```

And a call to mapper function is like -

```
/**return array of MatEducation Objects.*/
$arrayOfObject = array();
foreach ($result as $key=>$row) {
    $arrayOfObject[$key] = $this->map->toMatEducation($education, $result[$key]);
}
return $arrayOfObject;
```

Since by default all the values are passed are 'pass by value' thus the `$education` object must not change and should return a copy of it from function. If its still changing than at the time of assignment to `$arrayOfObject[$key]` a new copy should be generated. So my question is why all the index of `$arrayOfObject` are pointing to same object.?
**EDIT** this is the array what i am getting now.

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(MatEducation)[11]
      private 'id' => int 1
      private 'eduId' => string '4' (length=1)
      private 'degree' => string 'BCA' (length=3)
      private 'institute' => string 'CET' (length=3)
  1 => 
    object(MatEducation)[11]
      private 'id' => int 1
      private 'eduId' => string '4' (length=1)
      private 'degree' => string 'BCA' (length=3)
      private 'institute' => string 'CET' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects themselves are passed by value, but their properties aren't.

```
$a = new stdclass;
$a->p = 0;
$b = $a;
$b->p = 1;
```

`$a->p` would be changed into 0. If you change `$b` now, it would not affect `$a` itself, but changing the **properties** of `$b` would affect the properties of `$a`. Although they are not the same variable, they reference to the same object.

Note: That's not true to arrays though - two variables that are not by reference would not reference to the same array. For example, `$a = [0]; $b = $a; $b[0] = 1;` would not change the value of `$a[0]` unless it was `$b =& $a`, but this is not true for objects.

A simple solution to your case is to use `clone`. In your example, if you used `toMatEducation(clone $education, ...)` instead, it would work.

Comment: Thank you i understood now. and a bonus question.. what is that in square bracket against every object like `object(MatEducation)[11]` this [11]?

Comment: I am not quite sure. I don't know which method of var printing you used, but I guess it has something to do with the object's identifier. `php -r 'var_dump(new stdclass);'` outputs `object(stdClass)#1 (0)`, where the `#1` means that it is the first object constructed in this runtime (I guess), which may be the same thing as your `[11]`.

Comment: I was just doing `var_dump`. And yes they are identifier for object and counts from 1 for ever script increment by 1 if new object is created regardless of class. and if two objects are clone then their identifiers would be same. thank you again.  and `Marry Chrishmass`

Comment: Did you mean `$b = clone $a` or `$b = $a` by "clone"?

Comment: If `$a` is created first then it has id 1. and i clone `$b = clone $a` then `$b` will also have id 1. if `$b` is not a clone but independent object(same or any class) then it will have id 2(or depend upon number of objects created between `$a` and `$b`).. sorry for poor English