# How can a clone create a new version of a singleton?

Tags: php, oop, object, clone

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34463998/5341428) question and got a good solution. I understand how an object can be created without `new` (which I thought was the only way to construct an object).

I learned that by creating a singleton class we force a class to instantiate only once.

```
// a simple singleton class.
class Singleton
{
    private static $object = null;
    private function __construct() {}
    public static function createObject()
    {
        if (self::$object == null) {
            self::$object = new Singleton();
        }
        return self::$object;
    }
}
```

---

```
//$obj = new Singleton(); Obviously an error

$obj1 = Singleton::createObject();
// object(Singleton)[1]

$obj2 = Singleton::createObject();
// object(Singleton)[1]
// $obj1 and $obj2 are same. Both have same id = 1

$obj3 = clone $obj1;
// object(Singleton)[2]
// $obj3 is a new  instantiate. id = 2
```

How is this happening? How does the `clone` work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent cloning singletons add private method __clone `private function __clone() {}`.

Answer (score 2):

> I learned that by creating a singleton class we force a class to instantiate only once.

Yes, if we use the method we actually designed to create the object. Even though the idea of singleton is to share a single instance of an object throughout an application, it is still an *instance* of an object.

As such, an instance of an object can be cloned at will. Nothing prevents it from being cloned. What prevents duplicating the instance is using the `createObject()` method. (For the records, it would be better named `getObject()`)

so in order:

```
$obj1 = Singleton::createObject();
// the method call creates the instance with new
// assigns it to the property of the singleton class
// then returns it

$obj2 = Singleton::createObject();
// the method returns the instance from the first method call
// as it is still defined in the static property
// BOTH $obj1 and $obj2 are the same instance of an object

$obj3 = clone $obj1;
// here, we use the clone keyword.
// this has nothing to do with our singleton, yet
// it simply clones an instance of an object. 
// $obj1 is an instance of an object. It is therefore cloned.
```

Now, if you really wish for clone to return the same instance, you can as mentioned by MaxP define the `__clone()` magic method in the `Singleton` class.

```
function __clone()
{
    return self::createObject();
}
```

Which would return the correct instance, as any other call to `createObject()`.